# How to disable 'drop' command in phpPgAdmin?

Tags: php, phppgadmin

I want to disable 'drop' for tables and databases in phpPgAdmin, I don't want to create separate role to limit this rather just want to disable it in the application itself by changing some settings in config files(hopefully). Does anything similar to `AllowUserDropDatabase`of phpMyAdmin exists here?